# A map on $S^1$ with no recurrent points.

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, examples-counterexamples

We say that $x$ is a recurrent point of a topological space $X$ with respect to a map $T \colon X \to X$ if for every neighborhood $V$ of $x$, there exists $n \geq 1$ such that $T^n(x) \in V$. I am looking for an example of a map $T \colon S^1 \to S^1$ with no recurrent point. Clearly, $T$ cannot be continuous because we have a theorem that, if $X$ is compact and $T \colon X \to X$ is continuous, then there exists a recurrent point of $X$ with respect to $T$. But I am unable to find an example. Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Subdivide $S^1$ into countable intervals appropriately and consider a map shuffling them

Comment: Hmm, I know that if $X$ is compact *Hausdorff*, then we have such a theorem. Does it really hold for compact non-Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: Is topological dynamics even interesting for non-continuous maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can find such a map using the axiom of choice. Define an equivalence relation on $S^1$, where two points are in the same class when the length of the arc joining them is a rational fraction of $\pi$. We will give a recurrent-point-free map on each equivalence class.

Let $A:=[0,2\pi)\cap (2\pi \mathbb Q)$; each equivalence class is a rotated copy of $A$. We first give a transformation $T:A\to A$ with no recurrent points. Let $\ell(x)$ be the linear map taking $[0,2\pi]$ to $[1/2,2]$, such that $\ell(0)=1/2$ and $\ell(2\pi)=2.$ Then
$$
T(x)={\ell^{-1}}\left(\frac{\ell(x)+\frac2{\ell(x)}}{2}\right)
$$
Note that the map $x\mapsto (x+2/x)/2$ on the domain $[1/2,2)\cap \mathbb Q$ has no recurrent points, since iterating the map converges to the gap at $\sqrt 2$. We are using $\ell$ to stretch this map around the circle.

For each equivalence class, $C$, use the axiom of choice to choose a homeomorphism from $C$ to $A$, then define $T|_C$ by using this identification with $A$.